# Exception during running the graph: Unable to get element from the feed as bytes

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I'm using a beam pipeline to preprocess my text to integers bag of words, similar to this example https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/reddit_tft/reddit.py

```
words = tft.map(tf.string_split, inputs[name])
result[name + '_bow'] = tft.string_to_int(
    words, frequency_threshold=frequency_threshold)
```

Preprocessing and training seem to work fine. I train a simple linear model and point to the transform function and run an experiment.

The saved_model.pbtxt seems to have the dictionary saved and my goal is to be able to deploy this model on google cloud ml for prediction and query it with raw text as input:

```
{"inputs" : { "title": "E. D. Abbott Ltd", "text" : "Abbott of Farnham E D Abbott Limited was a British coachbuilding business" }}
```

When running

```
gcloud ml-engine local predict \
    --model-dir=$MODEL_DIR \
    --json-instances="$DATA_DIR/test.json" \
```

I get the below error, no idea what I'm doing wrong.

### Source code / logs

WARNING:root:MetaGraph has multiple signatures 2. Support for multiple signatures is
limited. By default we select named signatures.
ERROR:root:Exception during running the graph: Unable to get element from the feed a
s bytes.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/ml_engine/local_predict.py", line 136, in 
main()
File "lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/ml_engine/local_predict.py", line 131, in mai
n
instances=instances)
File "/Users/xyz/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/cloud_ml_engin
e_sdk/prediction/prediction_lib.py", line 656, in local_predict
_, predictions = model.predict(instances)
File "/Users/xyz/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/cloud_ml_engin
e_sdk/prediction/prediction_lib.py", line 553, in predict
outputs = self._client.predict(columns, stats)
File "/Users/xyz/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/cloud_ml_engin
e_sdk/prediction/prediction_lib.py", line 382, in predict
"Exception during running the graph: " + str(e))
prediction_lib.PredictionError: (4, 'Exception during running the graph: Unable to g
et element from the feed as bytes.')

```
def feature_columns(vocab_size=100000):
    result = []
    for key in TEXT_COLUMNS:
        column = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_integerized_feature(key, vocab_size, combiner='sum')
    result.append(column)
return result

model_fn = tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier(
      feature_columns=feature_columns(),
      n_classes=15,
      model_dir=output_dir
    )  

def get_transformed_reader_input_fn(transformed_metadata,
                                    transformed_data_paths,
                                    batch_size,
                                    mode):
  """Wrap the get input features function to provide the runtime arguments."""
  return input_fn_maker.build_training_input_fn(
      metadata=transformed_metadata,
      file_pattern=(
          transformed_data_paths[0] if len(transformed_data_paths) == 1
          else transformed_data_paths),
      training_batch_size=batch_size,
      label_keys=[LABEL_COLUMN],
      reader=gzip_reader_fn,
      key_feature_name='key',
      reader_num_threads=4,
      queue_capacity=batch_size * 2,
      randomize_input=(mode != tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.EVAL),
      num_epochs=(1 if mode == tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.EVAL else None))


transformed_metadata = metadata_io.read_metadata(
    args.transformed_metadata_path)
raw_metadata = metadata_io.read_metadata(args.raw_metadata_path)

train_input_fn = get_transformed_reader_input_fn(
    transformed_metadata, args.train_data_paths, args.batch_size,
    tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

eval_input_fn = get_transformed_reader_input_fn(
    transformed_metadata, args.eval_data_paths, args.batch_size,
    tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.EVAL)

serving_input_fn = input_fn_maker.build_parsing_transforming_serving_input_fn(
        raw_metadata,
        args.transform_savedmodel,
        raw_label_keys=[],
        raw_feature_keys=model.TEXT_COLUMNS)

export_strategy = tf.contrib.learn.utils.make_export_strategy(
    serving_input_fn,
    default_output_alternative_key=None,
    exports_to_keep=5,
    as_text=True)

return Experiment(
    estimator=model_fn,
    train_input_fn=train_input_fn,
    eval_input_fn=eval_input_fn,
    export_strategies=export_strategy,
    eval_metrics=model.get_eval_metrics(),
    train_monitors=[],
    train_steps=args.train_steps,
    eval_steps=args.eval_steps,
    min_eval_frequency=1
)
```

Comment: Unrelated: if you set min_eval_frequency to something higher than 1 (1000 is usually a good number) you should see better performance while training

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs for build_parsing_transforming_serving_input_fn() says it makes an input function that applies transforms to raw data encoded as tf.Examples as a serialized string. Making things more complicated, that string then has to be base64 encoded to send to the prediction service (see [section Data encoding](http://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects/predict))

I would recommend using build_default_transforming_serving_input_fn() which is for json input. Then your json file should just have

```
{ "title": "E. D. Abbott Ltd", "text" : "Abbott of Farnham E D Abbott Limited was a British coachbuilding business" }
{ "title": "another title", "text" : "more text" }
...
```

Comment: So it works locally with  
  
gcloud ml-engine local predict \  
    --model-dir=$MODEL_DIR \  
    --json-instances="$DATA_DIR/test.json" \  
  
However, loading the model on Cloud ML and requesting prediction  
gcloud ml-engine predict \  
    --model $MODEL_NAME \  
    --version $VERSION \  
    --json-instances="$DATA_DIR/test.json" \  
  
returns  
`
{  
  "error": "Prediction failed: Exception during model execution:   AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details=\"input size does not match signature\")"  
}  
  
Any idea what's going on?

Comment: when sending to the service, the body of the request should look like: {"instances": [{"title": "X", "text": "Y"}]. Is that what you have?